# Is a function differentiable in $x$ if $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\infty$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

All the definitions of differentiability I found (Wolfram Mathworld for instance) only require this limit to exist, but say nothing about the domain in which that has to happen.

So what if that limit is $\pm\infty$? Wouldn't (in the "normal" interpretation of a function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, for instance) the slope of the tangent of $f$ in $x$ be undefined?

Edit: [a link clearing it up.](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/calctopic1/contanddiffb.html)

Comment: No, it is not differentiable if the limit of the derivative does not exist. Infinity is not considered an answer for a limit to exist.

Comment: exits in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: We *generally* don't consider such limits to "exist".  We say they are "divergent".  Check the definition of limit.  Basically we require a function to approach a real value in ever decreasing distance as the argument of the function approaches the limit point -- which a divergent limit certainly does not.

Comment: Consider  $x=4$ what is its gradient

Comment: @Karl Misread $x$ as $y$ at first, that's what I'm asking basically.

Comment: The gradient is undefined. As others have pointed out your confusion lies in thinking infinity is a limit rather than diverging.

Comment: @Karl Yeah I got that now, ty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate case of terminology getting the better of us. The definition of a limit is

> The limit of the function $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ exists if there is a number $L$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In this case, we say that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L.$$

So the limit, if it exists is a number. Infinity is not a number, so technically, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$, the limit doesn't exist. And yet it is infinity. It's confusing at first, but once you get used to it, it's not too bad.

Comment: Oh so I was looking in the wrong place, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be differentiable, we require that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = L,$$
where $L \in \mathbb{R}$.
Sometimes the wording is "the limit exists *and is finite*,"
but other times the finite portion is dropped, and the phrase "limit exists" means, in particular, that the limit is not $\infty$.